# How to do a "svn copy without externals" ?

Tags: svn, svn-externals, svn-propset

I have a branch A with externals

I need to copy the content (without the externals) to a tag B. How to proceed ?

I tried,

```
svn copy A B --ignore-externals
```

It did not work.
Please note that A and B are complete https paths.

Comment: In what way didn't it work? Did the command not run, or did it copy but with the externals?

Comment: It copied with externals.

Comment: Does it work properly if you put the command option before the file path arguments, i.e. `svn cp --ignore-externals A B`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misunderstanding what --ignore-externals is for on the copy subcommand. This flag only affects working-copy operations. When you copy one working-copy path to another, it prevents svn from processing all the svn:externals properties on copied items to check out their targets. It does *not* prevent svn from copying the properties themselves; those get copied along with the folders they have been set on. Removing those properties would be a change to the copied objects, and svn does not change objects while it copies them.

You will either need to check out your tag, remove the externals, and commit; or, do the copy within your working copy, and edit to remove the externals prior to commit.